# Не отображается background кнопки

Tags: java, android, button

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="?attr/colorBackgroundFloating"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="25dp">


<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@drawable/my_round_button"
    android:onClick="onClick"
    android:text="@string/button_1"
    android:visibility="visible"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

my_round_button

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="ring">
<solid android:color="#FFFFFF"/>

</shape>
```

Обьясните, что не так

Answer (score 1):

Замените

```
android:shape="ring"
```

на

```
android:shape="rectangle"
```

Для закругливания углов используйте `corners`:

```
<corners android:bottomRightRadius="16dp"
    android:bottomLeftRadius="16dp"
    android:topRightRadius="16dp"
    android:topLeftRadius="16dp"/>
```

Полная разметка:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">
<solid android:color="#eeff0000" />
<corners android:bottomRightRadius="16dp"
    android:bottomLeftRadius="16dp"
    android:topRightRadius="16dp"
    android:topLeftRadius="16dp"/>
</shape>
```

Comment: Не отображается

Comment: В вашей разметке `my_round_button` цвет белый установлен, если и фон белый, тогда будет казаться что не отображается. Скопируйте в вашу  `my_round_button` весь код разметки, который я скинул, и тогда будет отображаться.

Comment: так и сделал, как написано

Comment: Если не устанавливать кнопке бэкграунд, отображается она?

Comment: если не устанавливать, то отображается